# Prove the inequality $(x+y+z)^3>27(y+z-x)(z+x-y)(x+y-z)$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I was trying to prove the equation

$(x+y+z)^3\gt27(y+z-x)(z+x-y)(x+y-z)$

I've proved $(x+y+z)\gt 27xyz$ before by AM-GM inequality. However, I'm confused with what I should do to prove this equation.
Can you help?

Comment: Just use the AM-GM inequality again, with $y + z - x$, $z + x - y$, and $x + y -z$ in place of $x,y$, and $z$. Note that they have to be nonnegative quantities (such as side lengths of a triangle) for this to work.

Comment: Did you forget to mention that $x, y, z$ are the sides of a triangle? See for example  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4164018/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775288/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(x%2By%2Bz)%5E3%3E27(y%2Bz-x)(z%2Bx-y)(x%2By-z)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MartinR: Don't seem to need this assumption. Assume WLOG that $x\le y\le z$. Then $y+z-x>0$, $z+x-y>0$. If $x+y\le z$ (i.e., it  is not a proper triangle), then the RHS is non-positive, and the LHS is positive. So the inequality holds. If all three are positive, apply AM-GM as Zarrax suggested.

Comment: @markvs: You are right. The first link from my previous comment does not make that assumption.  But we need that $x, y, z$ are positive, which is not stated in the question.

Comment: @MartinR: Then it is a duplicate question? The accepted answer there is what Zarrax suggested. This should be closed then?